# Stopping New page Auto Publish

Tags: html, kentico

using Kentico 9

When you create a new page and click save, it automatically publishes the page and makes it live.  Is it possible to create a custom workflow that, while still saving the page, puts it into a draft/edit mode for approval before moving on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use the Default workflow for this purpose. Every Kentico version/license has at least basic workflow functionality.

All you need to do is enable it by specifying the Scope.

See https://docs.kentico.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/59637966 for more information.